# Geny Motion v2.4.0. Virtualization engine not found. Plugin loading aborted

Tags: android, virtualization, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion v2.4.0 on my windows 7 OS. These installer is packaged with virtual box. After Installation, when I try to launch Geny motion, It says loading plugins and a pop up comes for virtual box . On OK, I get this error Virtualization engine not found. Loading Plugins aborted. I have enabled Virtualization features in my BIOS settings. I am able to run default Android Emulator on my box. The Virtual Box version  with Geny motion is 4.3.12. I have tried uninstall and install but the problem persists.

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue. Genymotion's support doesn't respond. Windows 10, Tried reinstall, install virtual box as standalone. Virtualization is on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Genymotion not working on windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913609/genymotion-not-working-on-windows-10) and/or [Genymotion error after windows 10 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781326/genymotion-error-after-windows-10-upgrade/32101818)

Comment: check my answer below if it works marked it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

### I solved this issue. It's working fine now.

I'm using:

```
+ Window 10
+ VirtualBox-5.0.2-102096-Win
+ Genymotion-2.5.3
```

**Step 1**: We should set **Run as this program as an administrator** & **Compatibility mode Windows 8** for those file.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
    + VBoxHeadless.exe
    + VBoxManage.exe
    + VirtualBox.exe
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
    + genymotion.exe
```

**Step 2**: My Computer -> Manage-> Device Manager-> Network adapters

Remove all items with name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethenet Adapter #...

**Step 3**: Open Virtual Box and go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks

Remove all and create new host with information:

```
Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.1.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.1.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.1.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.1.199
```

**Step 4**: Run Genymotion again. It's will work.

### [> Screenshots](http://s1187.photobucket.com/user/bjngboong/slideshow/Genymotion)

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall genymotion 2.4.0 and install version 2.0.3. it works fine  with windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `Genymotion-log.zip` in **C:\Users\%YOUR USER%**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using GenyMotion 2.0.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.6. My problem was I have an existing host-only adaptor that is used by Vagrant. I can't simply delete it, it will trash my Vagrant VM.

Create a new host-only adaptor in the Virtual Box global settings. Give it a separate address space from any existing host-only adaptors. For example, I set mine up as follows, where I also have a vboxnet0 (used by Vagrant) that uses 192.168.56.x

name: vboxnet1 IPV4 address: 192.168.57.1 mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP: address 192.168.57.100 mask: 255.255.255.0 low bounds: 192.168.57.101 high bound: 192.168.57.254

Then, edit your existing GenyMotion VM to use this host-only adaptor, and restart it from GenyMotion.

Note:- first you have to start virtual box then the genymotion.

Good luck!