# Not able to open emulator in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run emulator in android studio it is showing below error

Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_21 was killed.

Comment: try to  power of your virtual machine then restart device

Comment: If not working still then check system image is updated or not.if not then update it.

Comment: can you post full error message?

Comment: Check the configuration of your device like ram,graphics. Use a phone with lesser resolution

Comment: Yes actually now I am updating system image. let me tell you after what happens

Comment: D:\Excel\Android_kit\android-sdk.tar\home\jigar\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_21
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M

Comment: emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 192MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

Comment: log is showing all these error

Comment: ok . now your emulator heap size is low so its give error

Comment: so what to do now ???

Answer (score 0):

You should Increase your ADB emulator Heap to the minimum required

Follow steps to increase Heap Size.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: no actually my system image update is going on so after update i will do this

Comment: What heap size and ram size should I set in order to run emulator...my pc ram is 2GB.

Comment: @poojagajera set RAM size to 1024 MB And HEAP Size to 512 MB

Comment: D:\Excel\Android_kit\android-sdk.tar\home\jigar\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd final_device_API_21
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7

Comment: Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

Comment: I have made changes but still it is showing same error :                                                      Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD final_device_API_21 was killed.

Comment: change RAM Size to 512 Mb

Comment: same error:    Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: @poojagajera if still its not work then download genymotion

Comment: this time I also changed resolution still it is showing same error

Comment: I want to run program in emulator just to see SQLite Database...will it work in genymotion??

Comment: google it. you get link for it. and in that download with virtualbox pakage

Comment: try this Prefrences>android>DDMS and you will see ADB connection timeout extend it to 20000

Comment: Where Preferences located in android I am not able to find

Comment: I have downloaded genymotion but it is showing virtual box error

Comment: Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR).

Comment: i think its bug in vm see this https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13504?cversion=1&cnum_hist=1

Comment: when I start device in virtual box I am getting error

Comment: Which virtual box version you are using

Comment: @poojagajera i am using Linux so its different version then you . and have you downlaod Genypackge with VM

Comment: means ?? I have downloaded genymotion with virtual box from gnymotion site. now this virtual box version is not working so i am downloading virtual box version 4.3.12

Comment: now let see what happen....which tool u r using to view and modify SQLite database.

Comment: Yes I have already downloaded but I want to generate database file to open in SQLite browser which I am not able to geneate bcoz my emulator does not work and now virtual box also showing error

Comment: @poojagajera have you download lower VM version?

Comment: yes I have downloaded . but it is showing error like virtulization engine doesn't found now what to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964677/geny-motion-v2-4-0-virtualization-engine-not-found-plugin-loading-aborted

Comment: nothing worked...when I start virtual device window remain blank